# How to set the cursor staring position in UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I am developing one application.In that i set the text filed border width as 1o base don my requirement.So now the first character of text filed will be hidden by border color.SO please tell me how can i set the cursor staring position for UITextField.

Comment: Do you want to add space before the cursor?

Comment: Try this out. This will create a padding in your textfield.

UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 50)];
self.textfield.leftView = paddingView;
self.textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `UIview` with border and add `UITextField` inside `UIView`

```
 UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        [baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [baseView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [baseView setClipsToBounds:NO];
        baseView.layer.borderColor =[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;// UIColorFromRGB(0Xcccccc).CGColor;
        baseView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        [self addSubview:baseView];
UITextField* txtField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, frame.size.width-2,  frame.size.height-2)];
        [txtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[baseView addSubview:txtField];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a subclass of UITextField and use that.

Override these methods in your subclass. They will add space from left side in your textfield.

```
// placeholder text reposition
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 0);
}

// text reposition
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 0);
}
```